# perl dbi:odbc crashing/using strange file

Tags: linux, perl, odbc, dbi

I'm trying to solve an issue where a script crashes with little-to-no error information on one server (`db1`), but not on another server (`db2`), despite both environments being identical in every way (except one) that I can find.

Here is the script, `test.pl`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;
use Data::Dumper;

$ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH} = "/var/local/odbc";
$ENV{ODBCHOME}        = "/var/local/odbc";
$ENV{ODBCINI}         = "/etc/odbc.ini";

my $dbh = DBI->connect( "dbi:ODBC:db", "foo", "bar" ) or die "$DBI::err\n$DBI::errstr\n$DBI::state\n";
$dbh->{RaiseError} = "0";
$dbh->{AutoCommit} = "1";
$dbh->{LongReadLen} = 1024;

#$dbh->{TraceLevel} = 10;

my $sth = $dbh->prepare( "SELECT * FROM table WHERE x='y'" ) or die "$DBI::err\n$DBI::errstr\n$DBI::state\n";
$sth->execute or die "$DBI::err\n$DBI::errstr\n$DBI::state\n";

my $data = $sth->fetchall_hashref( 'x' );
print Data::Dumper->Dump( [$data] );
```

And here is the output (note: the death is at `$sth->execute`):

```
$ ./test
DBD::ODBC::st execute failed: [DataDirect][ODBC SQL Server Driver] (SQL-HY000)
[DataDirect][ODBC SQL Server Driver] (SQL-HY000)(DBD: st_execute/SQLExecute err=-1) at ./test line 24.
-1
[DataDirect][ODBC SQL Server Driver] (SQL-HY000)
[DataDirect][ODBC SQL Server Driver] (SQL-HY000)(DBD: st_execute/SQLExecute err=-1)
HY000
```

TraceLevel 10 does not shed light for me:

```
$ ./test
    DBI::db=HASH(0x1f2cc8e0) trace level set to 0x0/10 (DBI @ 0x0/0) in DBI 1.52-ithread (pid 27494)
    -> prepare for DBD::ODBC::db (DBI::db=HASH(0x1f2cc510)~0x1f2cc8e0 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE x='y'') thr#1effa010
    dbih_setup_handle(DBI::st=HASH(0x1f2cca60)=>DBI::st=HASH(0x1f2ccb60), DBD::ODBC::st, 1f2cca70, Null!)
    dbih_make_com(DBI::db=HASH(0x1f2cc8e0), 1f2d1e30, DBD::ODBC::st, 376, 0) thr#1effa010
    dbih_setup_attrib(DBI::st=HASH(0x1f2ccb60), Err, DBI::db=HASH(0x1f2cc8e0)) SCALAR(0x1f183620) (already defined)
    dbih_setup_attrib(DBI::st=HASH(0x1f2ccb60), State, DBI::db=HASH(0x1f2cc8e0)) SCALAR(0x1f1836a0) (already defined)
    dbih_setup_attrib(DBI::st=HASH(0x1f2ccb60), Errstr, DBI::db=HASH(0x1f2cc8e0)) SCALAR(0x1f183660) (already defined)
    dbih_setup_attrib(DBI::st=HASH(0x1f2ccb60), TraceLevel, DBI::db=HASH(0x1f2cc8e0)) 10 (already defined)
    dbih_setup_attrib(DBI::st=HASH(0x1f2ccb60), FetchHashKeyName, DBI::db=HASH(0x1f2cc8e0)) 'NAME' (already defined)
    dbih_setup_attrib(DBI::st=HASH(0x1f2ccb60), HandleSetErr, DBI::db=HASH(0x1f2cc8e0)) undef (not defined)
    dbih_setup_attrib(DBI::st=HASH(0x1f2ccb60), HandleError, DBI::db=HASH(0x1f2cc8e0)) undef (not defined)
    initializing sth query timeout to 0
    ignore named placeholders = 0
    SQLPrepare returned 0

    dbd_st_prepare'd sql f523212832, ExecDirect=0
        SELECT * FROM table WHERE x='y'
    <- prepare= DBI::st=HASH(0x1f2cca60) at ./test line 23
    -> execute for DBD::ODBC::st (DBI::st=HASH(0x1f2cca60)~0x1f2ccb60) thr#1effa010
    dbd_st_execute (outparams = 0)...
    dbd_st_execute (for hstmt 523212832 before)...
    dbd_st_execute (for hstmt 523212832 after, rc = -1)...
dbd_error: err_rc=-1 rc=0 s/d/e: 523212832/523051280/523050880
dbd_error: SQL-HY000 (native 0): [DataDirect][ODBC SQL Server Driver] (SQL-HY000)
dbd_error: SQL-HY000 (native 0): [DataDirect][ODBC SQL Server Driver] (SQL-HY000)
[DataDirect][ODBC SQL Server Driver] (SQL-HY000)
dbd_error: err_rc=-1 rc=0 s/d/e: 0/523051280/523050880
dbd_error: err_rc=-1 rc=0 s/d/e: 0/0/523050880
st_execute/SQLExecute error -1 recorded: [DataDirect][ODBC SQL Server Driver] (SQL-HY000)
[DataDirect][ODBC SQL Server Driver] (SQL-HY000)(DBD: st_execute/SQLExecute err=-1)
    !! ERROR: -1 '[DataDirect][ODBC SQL Server Driver] (SQL-HY000)
[DataDirect][ODBC SQL Server Driver] (SQL-HY000)(DBD: st_execute/SQLExecute err=-1)' (err#0)
    <- execute= undef at ./test line 24
DBD::ODBC::st execute failed: [DataDirect][ODBC SQL Server Driver] (SQL-HY000)
[DataDirect][ODBC SQL Server Driver] (SQL-HY000)(DBD: st_execute/SQLExecute err=-1) at ./test line 24.
-1
[DataDirect][ODBC SQL Server Driver] (SQL-HY000)
[DataDirect][ODBC SQL Server Driver] (SQL-HY000)(DBD: st_execute/SQLExecute err=-1)
HY000
    -> DESTROY for DBD::ODBC::st (DBI::st=HASH(0x1f2ccb60)~INNER) thr#1effa010
   SQLFreeStmt called, returned 0.
       ERROR: -1 '[DataDirect][ODBC SQL Server Driver] (SQL-HY000)
[DataDirect][ODBC SQL Server Driver] (SQL-HY000)(DBD: st_execute/SQLExecute err=-1)' (err#0)
    <- DESTROY= undef
    -> DESTROY for DBD::ODBC::db (DBI::db=HASH(0x1f2cc8e0)~INNER) thr#1effa010
  DBD::ODBC Disconnected!
       ERROR: -1 '[DataDirect][ODBC SQL Server Driver] (SQL-HY000)
[DataDirect][ODBC SQL Server Driver] (SQL-HY000)(DBD: st_execute/SQLExecute err=-1)' (err#0)
    <- DESTROY= undef
```

I `strace`d the runs on both servers and the ONLY difference happens toward the end of execution when the script on `db1` attempts to open and read from the file `/var/local/odbc/DDODBC.DAT` and proceeds to crash.  The run on `db2` does nothing of the sort and goes on to do its work successfully. After a good amount of filesystem crawling and file comparing, I've confirmed that the odbc.ini config files are the same for both servers and that the entire structure and contents of /var/local/odbc are also the same, except that DDODBC.DAT exists on `db1`, but not `db2`.  The environment variables are also the same.

Moving DDODBC.DAT somewhere else causes the script to run to success.  The file is re-created, used, and then the script goes on to do its work (as seen from `strace`).  If I replace the original DDODBC.DAT, the script crashes again.  The obvious conclusion here is that the file was at fault, with bad data, corruption, or the like.  `strace` on the new, successful, runs on `db1` only differ from those on `db2` by four 
lines:

```
open("/var/local/odbc/DDODBC.DAT", O_RDONLY) = 4
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(4, ..., 1212) = 1212
close(4)                                = 0
```

**What is the file DDODBC.DAT being used for and what causes it to be created?**  The Googles were no help for me.

For the record:

```
$ perl --version
This is perl, v5.8.8 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
$ uname -srmo
Linux 2.6.18-141.el5 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ odbcinst --version
unixODBC 2.2.11
$ perl -MDBD::ODBC -e 'print $DBD::ODBC::VERSION, "\n";'
1.13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataDirect has confirmed that the file DDODBC.DAT is (typically) created when there is a licensing conflict on the host.  In our case, our license is for servers with a maximum of 16 CPUs, however we installed the driver on a host with 24 CPUs.  The driver realized this, made note of it (with DDODBC.DAT), and will, eventually, switch itself into evaluation mode.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'll have to speak to your driver provider as I know for a fact DBD::ODBC does not use a DDODBC.DAT file and from the name it suggests DataDirect. The trace shows the call to SQLExecute errors and returns a general error (HY000) without any error text.

Comment: thanks for the tip.  i'm currently exploring some shared library differences, but looking to our provider for support will definitely come next.